# Distort circle so it looks like it is on a 3D surface (Illustrator CC)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Below is a diagram I have made in Illustrator CC:

[image]

How can I skew the shaded circle so that it looks like it is placed on the surface of the dashed shape?

Comment: What kimd of projection is the dashed shape in? And is the shape projected or wraped o  top of it?

Comment: I'm not that experienced with illustrator, so I just drew an arc, copied it, and then joined the two copies with straight lines. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes but to know how to make it look like it belongs, more accurately than just eyeball it, I would need to know what kind of projection your image uses. So its some kind of parallel projection like isometric ot trimetric?

Comment: I must admit I didn't think about that, I just eyeballed the shape. I would like it to look 'natural' however, so I assume I would want trimetric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used `rotation` and `warpping`. You go from imaging how it would look in 2D. Then find the relations of the circle to the surface(= the dashed shape) and afterwards just adjust your 3D view for the circle to have the same relations to the surface as it has in your 2D view. This way the circle will inherit the transformation of the surface. (By relations I especially mean parallelism)

1. `Rotate` the circle such that the bottom side of the circle  is parallel to the bottom side of the surface.
2. Use `warpping` to make sure each side of the circle is parallel to each side of the surface

By "each side of the circle," etc. I mean each side of the wrapping mesh.

Note: 3D perspective might distort the length relations. The distortion is described by the configuration of the perspective itself.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that image looks great. However, when you say 'wrapping', are you talking about Illustrator? I have not been able to find a tool which does this.

Comment: @RuviLecamwasam Thanks for your response. By 'wrapping' I meant 'warpping'. I did the above with Photoshop assuming the [Warp Tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctopP2DmJOQ) was available in Illustrator [see](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/874423?tstart=0) to read more about it. Have you tried using Illustrator's [Warp Tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lWqg8PlFo4) and combining different warp styles to achieve the desired result?